# "Did" as a habitual / emphatic marker in Southern varieties of British English

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar, aspect, varieties

I'm currently doing research on the salience of *did* as an emphatic marker in Southern varieties of British English as illustrated in (1). I'm comparing this with the salience of *did* as a habitual marker especially prominent in Southwestern varieties of British English. These varieties use *did* as a marker of habitual aspect similar to "used to", as illustrated in (2).

(1) "Don't you think Peter ran very fast?" - "Yes, he did run very fast, indeed."

(2) "I used to go to school every day." ~ "I did go to school every day."

I'm conducting this research with the help of FRED, the Freiburg Corpus of English Dialects. (Here, have some corpus data: https://fred.ub.uni-freiburg.de/)

As I'm doing statistical research, I'd like to know if there are any surveys out there indicating a percentage of how frequent emphatic and habitual "did" are?
I know the habitual use is much less common and regionally restricted, yet some numbers would be nice.

Thank you for your help!